# ASP.NET display related detail records via Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to asp.net and c#, I have been trying to duplicate and app done in php using MVC3, generating the code from the same database. I have a question about showing the detail records in my "Details" view.

```
namespace MvcApplication5.Models
{
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(masterDomain))]
[KnownType(typeof(masterFIP))]
[KnownType(typeof(masterSFPF))]
[KnownType(typeof(rgCountiesServed))]
[KnownType(typeof(rgKeyword))]
[KnownType(typeof(rgServicesProvided))]
public partial class rgOrganization
{
    public rgOrganization()
    {
        this.rgCountiesServeds = new HashSet<rgCountiesServed>();
        this.rgKeywords = new HashSet<rgKeyword>();
        this.rgServicesProvideds = new HashSet<rgServicesProvided>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int orgID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ORGANIZATION { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CONTACT_PERSON { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PHONE_NUMBER { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FAX_NUMBER { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string EMAIL_ADDRESS { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string WEBSITE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string STREET_1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string STREET_2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CITY { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ZIP_CODE { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string COUNTY { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FIPS { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MAILING_ADDRESS { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> SFPF { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> DOMAIN { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual masterDomain masterDomain { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual masterFIP masterFIP { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual masterSFPF masterSFPF { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<rgCountiesServed> rgCountiesServeds { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<rgKeyword> rgKeywords { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<rgServicesProvided> rgServicesProvideds { get; set; }
}
```

View Code

```
@model MvcApplication5.Models.rgOrganization

@{
  ViewBag.Title =  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORGANIZATION);
}
@section Scripts { 
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
}
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORGANIZATION)</h2>
<h3><span id="mailing_address">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MAILING_ADDRESS)
</span></h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.COUNTY)  COUNTY</legend>

    <div class="display-field">
        <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ORGANIZATION)</strong>
    </div>


    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CONTACT_PERSON)
    </div>
    <!-- would like to display services provided here -->
</fieldset>
```

My question is how do I access the 'rgCountiesServeds'and 'rgServicesProvideds' via Razor?

Comment: It's not at all clear what type `rgOrganization` represents with respect to your view.  You should show your view code.

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be members of your model.

So you can access the collection as

```
model.rgServicesProvided
```

To iterate through the collection, do something like this:

```
@foreach (var serv in model.ServicesProvided) {
  Service is @serv.ToString()<br/>
}
```

Replace serv.ToString() with whatever property you want to display.

Comment: I tried something like this. The actual service name is stored in another table, organizations can offer many services, in the rgServicesProvided table is the foreign key to the masterServices table which contains the descriptions.                               @foreach (var serv in Model.rgServicesProvideds) {
            @serv.masterService.service<br/>
        }

Comment: Did that work for you?  The question is highly dependent on your model classes and how you are populating them.  Are you using an ORM? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you can access the rgCountiedServeds and rgServicesProvideds just like the other properties of rgOrganization.  They are collections and properties of your model so you can loop over them in the View or create a drop down list for each of those properties.  I.e.,

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownCounties", Model.rgCountiesServeds)
```

Comment: Yes I saw the drop down example in the 'Edit' script that was generated. I just wanted to list them in the text only version. I tried something like this from the poster above.

Comment: I tried something like this from the poster above
        @foreach (var serv in Model.CountiesServeds) {
            @serv.masterFIPS.countyName<br/>
        }